# Should we edit signatures out of answers on sponsored tags?

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help, sponsored-tags, signatures

I just came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38441464/2756409) in a [sponsored tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-office). I know that standard operating procedure when editing is to remove such things because they don't relate to the answer (this isn't a letter or a blog post or something personal) and they don't add anything to it, either.

However, in this case the question is answered by a person certified by Microsoft on a question tagged with a Microsoft-sponsored tag (the sponsored tag is likely exactly why the user answered it).

Is there any good reason to leave such a signature in this case (i.e. is it an aspect of sponsoring a tag that sponsors prefer to leave)? I'm leaning toward no, but figured I would ask for input in case anyone had insight that I don't.

Comment: I don't see why we should leave it, that should be in the user's profile.

Comment: Hmmm... I see no reason why the sponsorship of the tag makes it more appropriate to keep a signature. I've always thought Stack was happy to get support people on here... But on STACK's terms.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, please edit out signatures, even if they are on answers posted in sponsored tags. Every post is already "signed" with a user's name and avatar, which links to their profile. That's where certifications and titles belong, not in the body of every answer that someone posts.

Comment: Hmm. I had the impression that we required in-question disclosure when you're talking about a product you're affiliated with, and had done so myself in the past. But I guess that might only apply if you're being promotional?

Comment: @JeremyBanks Yes, that's the way I understand it. If someone is asking about your work, it should be fine to go ahead and answer them. If you're the one to bring it up, then you should disclose your affiliation.

Comment: I feel like this is being removed because of its format and not its content. Don't get me wrong, I understand your point and I know you know the rules here better than most anyone. That said, I kind of agree with Jeremy that this is more disclosure than signature. The downside is that it just looks like a signature. If the post had started with some sort of plain English version, "Full disclosure, I am a developer on the Office Extensibility Platform Team at MSFT", would that be different? At what point does disclosure cross over into a signature? At what point is disclosure irrelevant?

Comment: @TravisJ Whether it's a preamble, greeting, signature, or tagline isn't that important. It's some irrelevant bit of information that can be edited out. I do see that there's a little bit of overlap here between signatures and disclosures, so this is worth bringing up, but I don't think a disclosure is needed in cases like this. The OP was already using Office.js, so Michael wasn't recommending it, just answering a question about it.

Comment: I think you can answer any question about your own technology, as long as it is not promotional. If you just answer the question how to use one of the features, there is nothing promotional to it. No disclosure is necessary then.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I think it isn't irellevant. It helps to understand the quality/sources of the answer. If he is affiliated with the company/even created a tool, his answers have more value.

Comment: @Mafii The value of an answer is based on the content of the answer itself, not who wrote it. Autobiographical information goes in the user profile.

Comment: @BilltheLizard alright, I agree partially, but 'I think' ;) Obviously, it's not like this on SO and I'm happy it isn't, but I persionally value answers from a creator of a tool higher, because its very likely its the best solution.

Comment: A reader can always hover over the author's avatar to see the "About me" excerpt.  The overriding issue here is precedent.  Do you really want to deal with arguments like "You let *him* use a signature, why can't I?"

Comment: @TravisJ The reason for disclosure is when the question is "How can I accomplish [x]?". You need to disclose that it is yours when you respond with "There is this tool *I wrote* that does exactly that in one line of code!" when your tool isn't necessarily the only (or best) solution out there. (Just like how Bill commented above you.)

Comment: @AlanMoore FWIW the affiliation may not be listed in the "About Me", particularly if it's a past affiliation (in an older answer). It doesn't need to be a full signature, anyway -- re-starting your name is certainly always redundant. The general position here does make sense to me, though.

Comment: Wow - in all my time on SO, I never knew/noticed that "A reader can always hover over the author's avatar to see the 'About me' excerpt."
...It never even occurred to me - I've hovered over the username plenty of times (esp for comments) as that looks 'actionable'.  Maybe I've never noticed it because if the "About me" is blank, hovering doesn't do anything.